# winexe can not exit if launched from lua

Tags: lua, popen, winexe

I running my program in lua and the winexe function is launched by lua, the problem is the winexe will start correctly but does not exit.
I had used file:flush(),file:close() and os.exit(), they all not working.Blow is my code:

```
local command = "/root/logoff_script";
 local file = io.popen(command,'r');
 file:write("\n");
 file:flush();
 local output = file:read('*all');
 file:close();
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: `popen` can't be used for reading AND writing.  Either read or write, [not both](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-10/msg00189.html).

Comment: you mean I should delete the "file:write("\n")" line? I tried, it didn't work

Comment: Yes, if you have selected mode "r" in `io.popen(command,'r')` then you can't write and flush.

Comment: Actually, I changed this code as  io.popen(command,'w') and it can work now. But I don't understand why it can not exit when I use 'read'

Comment: Because winexe waits for some user input prior to exiting?

Comment: so I need add some <EOF>?

Comment: You can `io.popen("echo Something | ./your_program","r")` to feed something to your program